# pig filter and getting original dataset

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig input file which looks like this:

```
1, cornflakes, Regular, Post, 10
2, cornflakes, Regular,General Mills, 12
3, cornflakes, Mixed Nuts, Post, 14
4, chocolate syrup, Regular, Hersheys, 5
5, chocolate syrup, No High Fructose, Hersheys, 8
6, chocolate syrup, Regular, Ghirardeli, 6
7, chocolate syrup, Strawberry Flavor, Ghirardeli, 7
```

I need to filter out the cornflakes which is less than 12 and I need to use the original set of data for the next step of filtering.

```
total = LOAD 'location_of_file' using PigStorage('\t') as (item_sl : int, item : chararray, type: chararray, manufacturer: chararray, price : int);
filter1 = FILTER total BY item == 'cornflakes' AND price < 12;
```

Now I need to use the original dataset after filter1 for the next step of filtering.

Comment: total is your original dataset.Why can't you use total for the next step of filtering? What is your end goal?

Comment: I will need to store total after the first filter, as a separate file and then apply the next filter on it

Comment: Ok so what is preventing you from doing it? Why do you have to store it to a separate file? The dataset is exactly same as the file you are loading it.Just create a new filter called filter2 = FILTER total BY (condition2); Just because you filter does not mean the original dataset will change.total will still have the entire dataset that was loaded from the input file.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind I do understand that filter doesn't change the original dataset, what I am trying to achieve is delete the filtered data from the original dataset and have the remaining data. It's like doing a delete using sql and keeping the data which passes the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SPLIT)

```
total = LOAD '/output/systemhawk/file_inventory/test34.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (item_sl : int, item : chararray, type: chararray, manufacturer: chararray, price : int);
SPLIT total INTO filter1 IF (item == 'cornflakes' AND price < 12),filter2 OTHERWISE;
DUMP filter2;
```

[image: Output]

Comment: doesn't get the right data, filters out other items too

Comment: what other items? what is the desired output?

Comment: using !=cornflakes and price >=12 brings in data only data which is not cornflakes and which is greater than 12. But my desired output is the total dataset without the records filtered by filter1, which is actually like doing a sql delete using the condition and keeping the original dataset (total) after removing the records from filter1

Comment: Instead of using filter1,you need to just do the opposite of what is in filter1 to get the total - filter1 records.This is exactly what !=cornflakes and price >=12 does.Only include records that are not in filter1 which uses ==cornflakes and price < 12.Why don't you include the desired output in the question?

Comment: This is my desired output:

Comment: 2, cornflakes, Regular,General Mills, 12
3, cornflakes, Mixed Nuts, Post, 14
4, chocolate syrup, Regular, Hersheys, 5
5, chocolate syrup, No High Fructose, Hersheys, 8
6, chocolate syrup, Regular, Ghirardeli, 6
7, chocolate syrup, Strawberry Flavor, Ghirardeli, 7

Comment: @Venkat. Take a look,i've edited the answer and the attached the output.

Comment: Have a related question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43355010/pig-programming-to-use-split-on-group-by-having-count

Answer (score 0):

When you run the command

```
filter1 = FILTER total BY item == 'cornflakes' AND price < 12;
```

It does not alter the original relation, total. Instead, it creates a new relation - filter1. Now, you have two relations to work with. You can access total at any point in the program. For example:

```
total = LOAD 'location_of_file' ...   -- total relation is created
filter1 = FILTER total BY item == 'cornflakes' AND price < 12; -- filter1 is created
...
filter2 = filter total by ... -- filter2 is created
...

/* Now count rows of original total (total is unchanged) */
grouped = group total by all;
total_row_count = foreach grouped generate COUNT(total) as cnt;
```

Comment: Yes, I do understand how it works but at the end of all my different filters, I need to keep the original dataset with the data removed from each of the filters. It's like deleting from the original dataset and having the data with the filters implemented

Comment: Then in that case, your last filterN is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [SPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SPLIT) ?

```
total = LOAD 'location_of_file' using PigStorage('\t') as (item_sl : int, item : chararray, type: chararray, manufacturer: chararray, price : int);
SPLIT total into F1_total IF (your considtion), f2_total if (your conditions);
```

**Thereafter you can use filtered set as f1_total and rest as f2_total. Apply conditions based on your needs**