# pig programming to use split on group by having count(*)

Tags: count, group-by, apache-pig

Input file is:

```
2, cornflakes, Regular,General Mills, 12
3, cornflakes, Mixed Nuts, Post, 14
4, chocolate syrup, Regular, Hersheys, 5
5, chocolate syrup, No High Fructose, Hersheys, 8
6, chocolate syrup, Regular, Ghirardeli, 6
7, chocolate syrup, Strawberry Flavor, Ghirardeli, 7

filter3 = LOAD 'location_of_file' using PigStorage('\t') as (item_sl : int, item : chararray, type: chararray, manufacturer: chararray, price : int);

SPLIT filter3 INTO filter4 IF (FOREACH (filter3 GROUP BY item) GENERATE group, COUNT(item < 3)), filter6_pass OTHERWISE;
```

It is like having a SQL with a group by on item having count(*) < 3

The desired output is:

```
4, chocolate syrup, Regular, Hersheys, 5
5, chocolate syrup, No High Fructose, Hersheys, 8
6, chocolate syrup, Regular, Ghirardeli, 6
7, chocolate syrup, Strawberry Flavor, Ghirardeli, 7
```

Comment: Are you looking for all items with a count > 3?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for all items less than 3

Comment: I would like to filter out all items less than 3 and get output with items having count> 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by item, get the count and then use filter on the count

```
A = LOAD 'location_of_file' using PigStorage('\t') as (item_sl : int, item : chararray, type: chararray, manufacturer: chararray, price : int);
B = GROUP A BY item;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,COUNT(A.item) AS Total;
D = FILTER C BY Total > 3;
E = JOIN A BY item,D BY $0;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE $0..$4;
DUMP F;
```

[image]

Comment: I need the data to remain the same, this groups by the item and counts on that item. But my desired output should be the same as the original dataset with the filter implemented

Comment: Join original dataset with D and get the desired columns,I've updated the script.

Comment: I tried to do a group by on multiple columns(item, manufacturer) and a count on that. I would like the output to be the original dataset without the records filtered by the group by on multiple columns

Comment: I get this error: the arity of the group by columns do not match

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43393266/count-on-group-by-on-multiple-columns-and-getting-the-original-dataset

Comment: the screenshot i've attached is exactly as the desired output you have included in the question.What is the issue now? If you want less than just change this step D = FILTER C BY Total > 3; to D = FILTER C BY Total < 3;

Comment: I am trying to group by on multiple columns

Comment: Why? Don't you get the output you want by using the script I've posted ?

Comment: this is a different use case, I have posted in a different thread. The output changes with that.