# count on group by on multiple columns and getting the original dataset

Tags: filter, count, apache-pig, multiple-columns

```
2, cornflakes, Regular,General Mills, 12    
3, cornflakes, Mixed Nuts, Post, 14  
4, chocolate syrup, Regular, Hersheys, 5   
5, chocolate syrup, No High Fructose, Hersheys, 8  
6, chocolate syrup, Regular, Ghirardeli, 6  
7, chocolate syrup, Strawberry Flavor, Ghirardeli, 7
```

Script

```
data_grp = GROUP data BY (item, type);
data_cnt = FOREACH data_grp GENERATE FLATTEN (group) AS(item, type), count(data) as total; 
filter_data = FILTER data_cnt BY total < 2;
```

I now need the original data with the filter applied and
my desired output is:

```
4, chocolate syrup, Regular, Hersheys, 5
6, chocolate syrup, Regular, Ghirardeli, 6
```

Comment: man, write your question clearly...

Answer (score 0):

filter_data will give you `chocolate syrup, Regular`.Join the filter_data with original dataset with item,type and get the desired result.

```
data_grp = GROUP data BY (item, type);
data_cnt = FOREACH data_grp GENERATE FLATTEN (group) AS(item, type), COUNT(data) as total; 
filter_data = FILTER data_cnt BY total < 2;
o_data = JOIN data BY (item,type),filter_data BY ($0,$1);
final_data = FOREACH o_data GENERATE $0..$4;
DUMP final_data;
```

Comment: Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve count using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Comment: count should be in capital